# Why is it appearing like I have pushed my code to github but I got to my profile and the code is not there?

Tags: github

What am I doing wrong?
Why will my code not show on github even though it appears to have pushed saying clean tree.
What am I supposed to be entering when it asks for git credentials osxkeychain?

Hello I have been watching video after video and reading the documentation on github and how to use it but nothing seems to be working. I have created a repo in my account and done the following:
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/stephBrandon/PythonNumberGuessingGame.git
git push -u origin main

it responded by saying initialized empty git repo in my folder which is true when hitting ls -a there is a .git file and there is a readme now as well

But when checking on my github none of the code it there and in the terminal it seems to be trying to access my old git hub account instead of my new one and I have no idea what to do now.

````
remote: Permission to stephBrandon/PythonNumberGuessingGame.git denied to stephanieBrandon.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/stephBrandon/PythonNumberGuessingGame.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403```

I had issues with the keycode and went into my key chain to see if I could change it there or if I was entering the wrong password but the one I had I deleted and it wont allow me to add another like some other videos I have watched.

Please help. I just want to know how to start using GitHub as I am in year 2 of my program and want to have a visible portfolio of my work without the frustrations of not figuring out how to use GitHub and it always seeming to take longer to upload to GitHub then the projects themselves sometimes.

If I am  missing something in my explanation above here is a copy of the terminal

```(base) stephaniebrandon@Stephanies-MacBook-Pro-2 Lab4Random % git commit -m "First commit for Python Guessing Game"
[main e955053] First commit for Python Guessing Game
 1 file changed, 44 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 lab4.py
(base) stephaniebrandon@Stephanies-MacBook-Pro-2 Lab4Random % git remote add origin https://github.com/stephBrandon/PythonNumberGuessingGame.git
error: remote origin already exists.
(base) stephaniebrandon@Stephanies-MacBook-Pro-2 Lab4Random % git remote add origin https://github.com/stephBrandon/PythonNumberGuessingGame.git
git branch -M main
git push -u origin main
error: remote origin already exists.
remote: Permission to stephBrandon/PythonNumberGuessingGame.git denied to stephanieBrandon.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/stephBrandon/PythonNumberGuessingGame.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
(base) stephaniebrandon@Stephanies-MacBook-Pro-2 Lab4Random % ls -a
.               ..              .git            README.md       lab4.py```

Additionally, when I try to do

```git push -u origin main```

it doesn't do anything but enter a loop that I have to control c to get out of.
````

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with using SSH instead of HTML, this should be the easiest way. This is assuming you have not local .git folder (you can delete it if you don't have git history you'd like to save).

### Part 1: Set up SSH with GitHub

First, open your terminal and run this command:
`ssh-keygen -b 4096 -t rsa`

When it asks you for a file name and save location, just hit `ENTER` to use defaults. Unless you feel it is necessary you can skip the password requirement the same way.

This will create a new (hidden!) folder named `.ssh` and two files in it: `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`. id_rsa.pub is your **pub**lic key. This is how you will authenticate with GitHub. Never share your private key (the other file).

Now, go to GitHub and sign in normally. Then, go to your profile settings (pictured below).

[image: profile settings]

Then to this setting...

[image]

And hit this green button:

[image]

Give it any title you'd like, such as the name of your computer, and paste in the contents of your id_rsa**.pub** file into the box and hit "Add SSH key". You should be able to open either of the two rsa_id files with any text program.

### Part 2: Setting up a Repo

In my experience, the easiest way to get Git configured correctly is to do this method rather than setting the upstream yourself.

First, make a new repository **on GitHub**. It doesn't matter if it's private or public, but add at least one file (such as a `readme` or `.gitignore`) to generate the first commit.

Now, you should be directed to your new repo. If you get a weird screen telling you to run some commands you likely didn't add any files when setting up the repo.

Assuming that you see the page, however, click the "code" button on the top right and select SSH. Copy it to the clipboard. (pictured below)

[image: code button]

### Part 3: Setting up your local repo

Open your terminal of choice and run
`git clone git@github.com:[your details here].git`
It should clone the repo and set the upstream for you. If you get an error here you likely have issues with your SSH settings.

Once you have the repo cloned, drag in any project you'd like and treat it like normal!

```
git status
git add *
git commit -m "Your message"
git push
```

Hope that works for you! Let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: Thank you, just to make sure I am doing this correctly. When you say "and paste in the contents of your id_rsa.pub file into the box and hit "Add SSH key". You should be able to open either of the two rsa_id files with any text program." I am not sure how to access these. I know you said text editor but I am used to opening things through vs code or my files could you clarify? Also, when I pressed enter after it asks me for a file and save location it states "Enter passphrase" am I suppose to be putting those files contents there?

Comment: Update... I pressed enter by accident, and it show Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/stephaniebrandon/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /Users/stephaniebrandon/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /Users/stephaniebrandon/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
<a bunch of sybols here> (I assume as the key fingerprint) stephaniebrandon@Stephanies-MacBook-Pro-2.local
The key's randomart image is:
<randomart img>
(base) stephaniebrandon@Stephanies-MacBook-Pro-2 Lab4Random %

Comment: You honestly can kind of spam enter once you run the rsa command. When it asks for a passphrase, just hit enter and when it asks you to confirm hit enter again. On windows you would right click, open with..., and then choose the program to do so with. 

If you were so inclined you definitely can open those files with VS Code, just run 
```code path/to/file.pub```
In your terminal. Both rsa_id files are just text documents without a file extension that would imply as much.

Comment: Oh, and don't worry about the key fingerprint or the random image art. I have never used those.

Comment: Thanks all that worked up until here: (base) stephaniebrandon@Stephanies-MacBook-Pro-2 Lab4Random % git commit -m "First commit"
[main 9f48936] First commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 160000 NumberGuessingGame
(base) stephaniebrandon@Stephanies-MacBook-Pro-2 Lab4Random % git push
fatal: The current branch main has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin main

(base) stephaniebrandon@Stephanies-MacBook-Pro-2 Lab4Random % git push --set-upstream origin main

Comment: now it is not doing anything and I have to press ^C to exit it. Any ideas? And it just updated to saying fatal:unable to connect to github.com: errno=Opertaion timed out

Comment: What does ```git remote -v``` say?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249127/discussion-between-dowdyj-and-devsteph).